# Time restrictions in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have different events wherein users can sign-up. These events have their own date and time schedules. How do I add a sort of a time restriction wherein it will automatically restrict the users from signing up?

For Example, I have an event scheduled on March 10, 2012. Users will only be allowed to sign-up for the event up to March 9, 2012.

My table for the events contains the following fields:

eventID/eventName/eventTime/eventDate/eventCapacity/eventDescription

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get event using eventTime/eventDate parameter and check today's date is smaller or not using datediff function.if date is bigger then reuse to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the event date and the current date and calculate the difference using PHP date object

```
   mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
   mysql_select_db("myDb")  

   $query="SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventName='$eventName' "; 
   $result=mysql_query($query);
   $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

   $currentTime= new DateTime("now UTC");
   $eventTime=new DateTime($row['thisEventDate']); 

   $interval=$eventTime->diff($currentTime);

   $days=$interval->format('%d');

   if($days<=1) {

   print "sorry too late, we're sold out";
   }  
   else {

   //allow for registration fields.

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

By comparing the current date and desired date or taking the difference or current date and desired date, and accordingly displaying the HTML form into the PHP if loop

Sample

```
if($days<=1) {

   echo "where were you wen i asked you to do so!!! ";
   }  
   else {

   <form>
field1
field2
...
</form>

   }
```

here, $days is difference of dates